# jQuery append implementation is breaking

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code that I am trying to alter –

**Original:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var name = '';
  var firstLastName = '[[T6:[[E48:[[S334:fr-id]]-[[S334:px]]:cons.first_name]]]] [[T6:[[E48:[[S334:fr-id]]-[[S334:px]]:cons.last_name]]]]';
  var screenname =  '[[T6:[[S48:0:screenname]]]]';

  if (screenname) {
    name = screenname;
  } else {
    name = firstLastName;
  }

  var splitName = name.split('');
  var nameCheck = splitName[splitName.length-1];

  jQuery('#personal_page_header h2').html("Support " + name + "'s Fundraiser" );
});
```

someone wrote this up and are no longer here, and what I'm trying to do now is figure out how to instead of replace the existing text, add to it.

So right now what this code does is it replaces the h2 content with the constituents registered name, or screenname.

What I'm trying to do now is append to that so that it will say something like

```
<h2>
  Welcome to my fundraiser
  <br/>
  "Support" + name + "'s Fundraiser"
</h2>
```

but unfortunately what I tried breaks the code and stops it from working.

what I tried to do is this:

```
jQuery('#personal_page_header h2').append('<span><br />"Support " + name + "'s Fundraiser"</span>' );
```

I've tried to do a variety of other things that gave the same unsuccessful result.

Any help would be really appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
jQuery('#personal_page_header h2').append("<span><br/>Support " + name + "'s Fundraiser</span>");
```

You've just got your quotations a little out of place.

Comment: ohhhh that makes sense, I was trying to follow a few examples I found but I never thought the quotations were the issue. brilliant, thank you Jeff, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate your code correctly, so if you'd like to keep the `"` use `'` to concatenate. Further you need to escape the `'` inside the string with `\`:

```
jQuery('#personal_page_header h2')
    .append('<span><br />"Support ' + name + '\'s Fundraiser"</span>');
```